# Benchmarking a WPF program's rate of display

Tags: c#, wpf, benchmarking

In [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642461/brushes-white-slows-graphics-demo-down) I mention that a WPF program slows down noticeably when I use `Brushes.White`.

Instead of saying "the program runs slower when I do *xyz*", it would be nice to get some actual timings.

How can I benchmark the rate at which that WPF program's display is being drawn?

Comment: You can use the [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx)

Comment: Don't forget the [patch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/08/24/timezone-patch-to-wpf-performance-profiling-tools-for-wpf-4-is-now-available.aspx).